# Replace templated function call by another "virtual" function call

Tags: c++, templates, macros

I have a strange C++ question.

If I have the following code:

```
template<int p1, int p2> class A {
    // SOME STUFF
};

template<int N> class B {
    // SOME STUFF
    template<int p1, int p2> A<p1,p2> func() {
       A<p1,p2> a(something);
       return a;
};
```

Now in the main, I want to access func():

```
int main(void) {
    B<12> b;
    b.func<6,2>();
}
```

And for some reason, I would like the exact same behaviour with the following code:

```
int main(void) {
    B<12> b;
    b(6,2);
}
```

Of course, it is impossible in theory because the template values p1 and p2 have to be resolved at compile time and so they can't be taken as a function parameter. So it is useless to try to overload "operator ()" in class B.

However, isn't there a way to have like an alias, meaning that in my code, the line:

```
b(x,y);
```

is just replaced by:

```
b.func<x,y>;
```

before the compilation tries to resolve the templates ? Like a kind of macro which would be specific to class B ?

Thank you in advance to your answers,

Benjamin.

Comment: you want to overload the operator ()

Comment: You can't.   For a function call, arguments are determined at run time.  Templates are expanded at compile time.   An `operator()` which accepts two `int` arguments, called using `b(6,2)` cannot return a `A<6,2>`

Comment: This looks like a [XY-Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Why do you need this? [...]And for some reason, ... [...] is most probably the problem...

Comment: However, it is possible with a macro. It's ugly, not reusable, and just a bad idea, but [possible](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25118cacbbe820f0).

Comment: You could make use of mechanism of tag dispatching...

Comment: How about `b(6_c, 2_c)` ? (using `std::integral_contant` and udl).

Comment: How is it related to virtuals? Do you really need ints and not e.g. chars? Can you do the other way (making p1, p2 runtime), perhaps in a base class of A, to which A would delegate (based on template parameters)?

Comment: It is not related to virtual, I used the word virtual in the sense that the function call I want to perform would not be an actual function call. And no, int or char have no importance in the problem. If p1 and p2 could be defined at runtime there would be no problem !

Comment: Are the ranges of p1 and p2 constrained in any way? If so, we could build a constexpr array of function specialisations and return a variant.

Comment: In the case I'm thinking of, yes, they are constrained by (0<=p1<=p2<N) where N is the template of class B. Could you tell me more about what you are thinking about?